# bootstrap-table does not populate inside angular view

Tags: angularjs, angular-ui-router, bootstrap-table

Placing bootstrap-table [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1mC.png) on the main page seems to work, but once it's placed into a view nothing happens.

Here is plunker to reproduce the issue: http://plnkr.co/edit/n0J91B?p=preview.
Question: how to modify this plunker to make both tables show the data?

```
<table data-toggle="table"
   data-url="/gh/get/response.json/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/tree/master/docs/data/data1/">
<thead>
<tr>
    <th data-field="name">Name</th>
    <th data-field="stargazers_count">Stars</th>
    <th data-field="forks_count">Forks</th>
    <th data-field="description">Description</th>
</tr>
</thead>
```

In the plunker there shall be two tables, but only the top one shows up, the bottom one only the header shows up:
[image]
[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KO1mC.png) http://bootstrap-table.wenzhixin.net.cn/examples/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got in contact with component authors and devs:
https://github.com/wenzhixin/bootstrap-table/issues/650

This lead to following solution (see details in link above):

```
// HOME STATES AND NESTED VIEWS ========================================
.state('home', {
    url: '/home',
    templateUrl: 'partial-home.html',
    controller: function($scope) {
      $(function () {
        $('[data-toggle="table"]').bootstrapTable();
      });
    }
})
```

Answer (score 0):

here is the plunker URL : 
everything working fine now , both tables showing data
http://plnkr.co/edit/n0J91B?p=preview

```
.state('about', {
            url: '/about',
            views: {
                '': { templateUrl: 'partial-about.html' },
                'columnOne@about': { template: 'Look I am a column!' },
                'columnTwo@about': { 
                    templateUrl: 'table-data.html',
                    controller: 'scotchController'
                }
            }

        });
```

Comment: hmm, still does not show up -- did you forget to save the plunker? also include code snipped is same as the original -- so not clear what's your intended answer